# Interchange the value of array according to Index

Tags: c

I am not clearly understand how to solve.

```
main()
{
    int a[10],n,i,j,temp1,max,temp[10];
    clrscr();

    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);       
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        temp[1] = a[0];
        temp[2] = a[temp[1]];
        a[temp[1]] = 0;
        temp[3] = a[temp[2]];
        a[temp[2]] = temp[1];   
        temp[4]=a[temp[3] ];
        a[temp[3]]=temp[2];
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        printf("%d",a[i] );
    getch();
}
```

Input: 3

```
2 0 1
```

Output

```
1 2 0
```

But for more I don't under stand.

```
like input: 6 
4 3 0 5 1 2 

Output
2 4 5 1 0 3
```

logic:
take an array like

```
i 0 1 2

a[i] 2 0 1
```

logic is `a[i]` goes to array's index and array value goes to its index.

```
a[0]=2 and index is 0
so after apply logic the element of a[2]=0
then
a[1]=0 so it goes to a[0]=1
and so on..
and also
apply it for "430512" to "245103"
```

Comment: Your logic is not clear to me. It's also not clear what the expected output is.

Comment: This is not at all safe as if the value of `a[i]` is something large like `100245` or some other large number ( or a negative number ), your logic ( as far as I have understood it ) will fail. You would either need a very large array, or you will have to restrict the input made by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the following `for` loop with your second `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
    temp[a[i]]=i;    
}
```

And then print the array `temp`.

Comment: Why? why would that work?

Comment: As i understand, he wants to that the value of the elementh index is assigned to index of element.Like, 
input:430512 for example first element 4 and its index 0 then he wants to 4th index is assinged to 0

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because it is static. You have to create dynamic way.
This code works for `4 3 0 5 1 2`

```
main()
{
    int a[10],n,i,j,temp1,max,temp[10], result[10];

    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);       
    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            if(i == a[j])
            {
                result[i]=j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        printf("%d",result[i] );
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Dynamic? Static? What?

Comment: Thanks I got the result.